# <body> only clickable where child elements fill it

Tags: javascript, ios, click, addeventlistener, touchstart

Please see my JS Fiddle on both Desktop and iPhone:

https://jsfiddle.net/5jb3x5cn/4/

I am using a `click eventListener` on `document.body`:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert(1);
})
```

I filled the background in blue, so that you can see the entire frame is being filled by the body and given it a height of `100vh`.

I have inserted one child element for the iPhone.

On desktop, you will notice you get an alert regardless of where you click on the `body`. On the iPhone, the alert is only displayed when you click on the child element. I can only assume the child element 'fills' the body with some space, where you can click on - regardless of the height the body is set to.

Interestingly enough `document.body.clientHeight` returns a value which would suggest the `body` has a decent clickable size.

Now if you head over to: https://jsfiddle.net/5t8arze9/1/

You will notice that the entire `body` is clickable. Here I have used the `touchstart` `eventListener`.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, a colleague this was solved as follows:

1. Detect iPhone via User-Agent
2. If iPhone, then combine `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` `eventListeners` to determine whether the user just 'clicked' or actually 'swiped'/'scrolled' the screen
3. If use clicked, open URL, if not - ignore
4. Non iPhones get the normal `click` listener set

Code:

```
if (body.addEventListener) {

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null) {

    var startX = 0;
    var startY = 0;
    var endX = 0;
    var endY = 0;

    body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
        startX = event.touches[0].pageX;
        startY = event.touches[0].pageY;
        endX = 0;
        endY = 0;
    }, false);

    body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
        endX = event.touches[0].pageX - startX;
        endY = event.touches[0].pageY - startY;
    }, false);

    body.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {
        if (!endX && !endY) {
            wallpaperClick(event);
        }
        startX = 0;
        startY = 0;
    }, false);

} else {
    body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        wallpaperClick(event);
    }, !1);
}

} else {
    body.attachEvent("onclick", function(event) {
        wallpaperClick(event);
    });
}
```

This however unfortunately does not quite answer *why*. This is somewhat vaguely explained here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile

Answer (score 0):

*False Code :*

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert(1);
})
```

**True Code :**

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert(1);
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. This code attaches the event to the document and not the body. This code also results in the same behaviour. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your CSS to really fill the screen. Even the backgroud is blue, you can see that your mouse cursor is not shown correctly.

Add

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

fiddle (update): https://jsfiddle.net/5jb3x5cn/10/

Comment: Well spotted, I had also tried this. The issue is, that you are unable to `click` on iPhone and you are on Desktop. The `touchstart` event however seems to work.

Comment: Ah. Interesting. Did my first fiddle work on the 4? We have been testing on a 6S. iOS 9.3.3

Comment: No. The body is aligned to it's inner elements until you set HTML and BODY to 100%. But this is default behaviour.

Comment: I believe I have found the answer: 

If we head down to the section "Safari Mobile" and look at the JS fiddle - we can replicate.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click